# Unity 2D Mobile Game Drawing Mechanic

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, touch, unityscript

My team and I are creating a simple mobile game that utilizes fast passed action using touch controls.

In this game we want to implement a spell casting feature similar to that of **Lost Magic** for the DS. For instance...https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-JYTGfagvWY

The user will open an area where they can use their finger to draw a shape of some sort.

Looking online, I found these links that **don't** quite match what I'm looking for:

- answers.unity3d.com/questions/318602/draw-line-in-2d-space-using-linerender.html
- answers.unity3d.com/questions/601640/correct-way-to-draw-on-screen-for-2d-game.html
- www.everyday3d.com/blog/index.php/2010/03/15/3-ways-to-draw-3d-lines-in-unity3d/

What is the best way to draw a simple shape and have it recognized by unity in order to cast a spell for example?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you need this done quickly. I would suggest the FingerGestures plugin.

You can define your own PointCloud gestures, and it does all the gesture recognition for you.

[More Info Here](http://fingergestures.fatalfrog.com/docs/manual:gestures:pointcloud)

Comment: After looking at the page, it seems great. Although the reviews say that it is very broken and buggy.

Not wanting to shell out the $45 now, I'm gonna try to use a different method first.

Thanks for the response!